# In which spaces can one "flip" the topology?

Tags: general-topology

This is just out of curiosity:

In which topological spaces can I relabel all closed sets as open and all open sets as closed and still obtain a valid topology?

For example, both the discrete and the indiscrete topolgy can be "flipped" for finite sets. The real topology cannot be flipped. Is there any good criterion for being a "flippable" topology?

Comment: Both of your examples are cases where all open sets are clopen, so generalizing that to all topologies whose open sets are closed is another obvious step. I have a hunch that the topology generated by left half-open intervals and the topology generated by right half-open intervals might be another example, but I didn't check the details.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology

Your spaces are closed under arbitrary intersections. These are called Alexandrov spaces.

Comment: Ooo, I hadn't heard this particular term before... :)

Comment: Also, any finite space as a special case.  They have an unusually strong homotopy theory, much of it worked out in the 60s.

Comment: @Randall every finite space is Alexandrov.

Comment: Yeah, I know that.  I'm pointing out a particularly successful special case.

Answer (score 6):

Let $T$ denote the topology, then $T^c:=\{U^c:U\in T\}$ is a topology if $T$ is closed under every kind of intersection (not just finite ones).